# position: fixed overlapping page

Tags: css, html, css-position

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Shmoyojoe/sZaxc/6/). I am making a grocery list web app, and I am making the top div a fixed position. When I do this, the div seems to overlap the rest of the page. I have tried using two positions in the css (`position: relative; position: fixed`) but this doesn't let the div stay fixed.

CSS (for the div):

```
#top {
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    background: #96f226;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #252525;
    position: relative;
    position: fixed;
}
```

HTML (for the div):

```
<div id='top'>Kitchen List</div>
```

Comment: Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/sZaxc/7/

Comment: yes...very much like that.

Comment: Ok, i have posted the answer below, Please accept it.

Comment: ok, i can accept in 5 min.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Wrap your content with `div` and give it the `margin-top` to the same height as your fixed content.

**[SEE DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/sZaxc/7/)**

HTML

```
<div id='top'>Kitchen List</div>
<br />
<div class="container">
    <input type='text' id='input'>
    <button id='click'>Add</button>
    <ol></ol>
    <div id='error'>Please enter a grocery item
        <br />
        <button id='eb'>Close</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
    margin-top: 50px;
}
```

Comment: It works only for the first page when printing from Opera (Web Kit)

Answer (score 3):

You need to add another div to wrap the content with a `margin-top`.

**DEMO**

http://jsfiddle.net/sZaxc/8/

**HTML**

```
<div id='main'>
    <!-- inputs etc -->
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#main {
    margin-top: 50px;
}
```

I also added a `z-index`and `top: 0`to your `#top`-div - just in case.

Answer (score -1):

It's because you have two positions. Remove one and make it:

```
#top {
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    background: #96f226;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #252525;
    position: fixed;
}
```

Comment: Wrong! The last position will override all the past defined position values! Thus, what you have done will work exactly the same as the code in the question.