# Why is my bottom div overlapping my other div and not stacked?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

So I have a div with the class of `flex-container` and I want it to be stacked on top of my other div that is beneath with the class of `black-bar` but for some reason the div with the class of `black-bar` is overlapping the bottom of the div with the class of `flex-container` and covers the bottom instead of being stacked on top of each other.

Why is that?

```css
.flex-container {
  max-width: 1700px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.black-bar {
  background-color: #242424;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="song-box">
    <img src="https://pro2-bar-s3-cdn-cf6.myportfolio.com/0d5a2028d7a7f8febf676a97648ea300/05851b218f8801ca2b106119_rw_1920.jpg?h=3e70946439d6e6326c1bd3efc5d20e51" alt="Nature" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
  </div>

  <div class="song-box">
    <img src="https://pro2-bar-s3-cdn-cf6.myportfolio.com/0d5a2028d7a7f8febf676a97648ea300/05851b218f8801ca2b106119_rw_1920.jpg?h=3e70946439d6e6326c1bd3efc5d20e51" alt="Nature" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
  </div>

  <div class="song-box">
    <img src="https://pro2-bar-s3-cdn-cf6.myportfolio.com/0d5a2028d7a7f8febf676a97648ea300/05851b218f8801ca2b106119_rw_1920.jpg?h=3e70946439d6e6326c1bd3efc5d20e51" alt="Nature" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
  </div>

  <div class="song-box">
    <img src="https://pro2-bar-s3-cdn-cf6.myportfolio.com/0d5a2028d7a7f8febf676a97648ea300/05851b218f8801ca2b106119_rw_1920.jpg?h=3e70946439d6e6326c1bd3efc5d20e51" alt="Nature" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
  </div>

  <div class="song-box">
    <img src="https://pro2-bar-s3-cdn-cf6.myportfolio.com/0d5a2028d7a7f8febf676a97648ea300/05851b218f8801ca2b106119_rw_1920.jpg?h=3e70946439d6e6326c1bd3efc5d20e51" alt="Nature" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
  </div>

  <div class="song-box">
    <img src="https://pro2-bar-s3-cdn-cf6.myportfolio.com/0d5a2028d7a7f8febf676a97648ea300/05851b218f8801ca2b106119_rw_1920.jpg?h=3e70946439d6e6326c1bd3efc5d20e51" alt="Nature" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
  </div>

  <div class="song-box">
    <img src="https://pro2-bar-s3-cdn-cf6.myportfolio.com/0d5a2028d7a7f8febf676a97648ea300/05851b218f8801ca2b106119_rw_1920.jpg?h=3e70946439d6e6326c1bd3efc5d20e51" alt="Nature" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
  </div>

  <div class="song-box">
    <img src="https://pro2-bar-s3-cdn-cf6.myportfolio.com/0d5a2028d7a7f8febf676a97648ea300/05851b218f8801ca2b106119_rw_1920.jpg?h=3e70946439d6e6326c1bd3efc5d20e51" alt="Nature" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
  </div>

  <div class="song-box">
    <img src="https://pro2-bar-s3-cdn-cf6.myportfolio.com/0d5a2028d7a7f8febf676a97648ea300/05851b218f8801ca2b106119_rw_1920.jpg?h=3e70946439d6e6326c1bd3efc5d20e51" alt="Nature" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
  </div>

  <div class="song-box">
    <img src="https://pro2-bar-s3-cdn-cf6.myportfolio.com/0d5a2028d7a7f8febf676a97648ea300/05851b218f8801ca2b106119_rw_1920.jpg?h=3e70946439d6e6326c1bd3efc5d20e51" alt="Nature" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
  </div>

  <div class="song-box">
    <img src="https://pro2-bar-s3-cdn-cf6.myportfolio.com/0d5a2028d7a7f8febf676a97648ea300/05851b218f8801ca2b106119_rw_1920.jpg?h=3e70946439d6e6326c1bd3efc5d20e51" alt="Nature" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
  </div>

  <div class="song-box">
    <img src="https://pro2-bar-s3-cdn-cf6.myportfolio.com/0d5a2028d7a7f8febf676a97648ea300/05851b218f8801ca2b106119_rw_1920.jpg?h=3e70946439d6e6326c1bd3efc5d20e51" alt="Nature" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
  </div>

  <div class="song-box">
    <img src="https://pro2-bar-s3-cdn-cf6.myportfolio.com/0d5a2028d7a7f8febf676a97648ea300/05851b218f8801ca2b106119_rw_1920.jpg?h=3e70946439d6e6326c1bd3efc5d20e51" alt="Nature" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
  </div>

  <div class="song-box">
    <img src="https://pro2-bar-s3-cdn-cf6.myportfolio.com/0d5a2028d7a7f8febf676a97648ea300/05851b218f8801ca2b106119_rw_1920.jpg?h=3e70946439d6e6326c1bd3efc5d20e51" alt="Nature" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
  </div>

  <div class="song-box">
    <img src="https://pro2-bar-s3-cdn-cf6.myportfolio.com/0d5a2028d7a7f8febf676a97648ea300/05851b218f8801ca2b106119_rw_1920.jpg?h=3e70946439d6e6326c1bd3efc5d20e51" alt="Nature" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
  </div>

</div>



<div class="black-bar">

</div>
```

Comment: For one, using `position:fixed` removes the element from the document flow, so they are treated like they are not there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [position: fixed overlapping page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19098294/position-fixed-overlapping-page)

Comment: about the duplicate suggested, in your case it's `bottom` instead of `top`. And for the explanation Swellar's comment is right.

Answer (score 2):

position relative will put it below your content, not filling the bottom of the page at all times

```css
.flex-container {
  max-width: 1700px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.black-bar {
  background-color: #242424;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="song-box">
    <img src="https://pro2-bar-s3-cdn-cf6.myportfolio.com/0d5a2028d7a7f8febf676a97648ea300/05851b218f8801ca2b106119_rw_1920.jpg?h=3e70946439d6e6326c1bd3efc5d20e51" alt="Nature" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
  </div>

  <div class="song-box">
    <img src="https://pro2-bar-s3-cdn-cf6.myportfolio.com/0d5a2028d7a7f8febf676a97648ea300/05851b218f8801ca2b106119_rw_1920.jpg?h=3e70946439d6e6326c1bd3efc5d20e51" alt="Nature" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
  </div>

  <div class="song-box">
    <img src="https://pro2-bar-s3-cdn-cf6.myportfolio.com/0d5a2028d7a7f8febf676a97648ea300/05851b218f8801ca2b106119_rw_1920.jpg?h=3e70946439d6e6326c1bd3efc5d20e51" alt="Nature" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
  </div>

  <div class="song-box">
    <img src="https://pro2-bar-s3-cdn-cf6.myportfolio.com/0d5a2028d7a7f8febf676a97648ea300/05851b218f8801ca2b106119_rw_1920.jpg?h=3e70946439d6e6326c1bd3efc5d20e51" alt="Nature" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
  </div>

  <div class="song-box">
    <img src="https://pro2-bar-s3-cdn-cf6.myportfolio.com/0d5a2028d7a7f8febf676a97648ea300/05851b218f8801ca2b106119_rw_1920.jpg?h=3e70946439d6e6326c1bd3efc5d20e51" alt="Nature" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
  </div>

  <div class="song-box">
    <img src="https://pro2-bar-s3-cdn-cf6.myportfolio.com/0d5a2028d7a7f8febf676a97648ea300/05851b218f8801ca2b106119_rw_1920.jpg?h=3e70946439d6e6326c1bd3efc5d20e51" alt="Nature" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
  </div>

  <div class="song-box">
    <img src="https://pro2-bar-s3-cdn-cf6.myportfolio.com/0d5a2028d7a7f8febf676a97648ea300/05851b218f8801ca2b106119_rw_1920.jpg?h=3e70946439d6e6326c1bd3efc5d20e51" alt="Nature" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
  </div>

  <div class="song-box">
    <img src="https://pro2-bar-s3-cdn-cf6.myportfolio.com/0d5a2028d7a7f8febf676a97648ea300/05851b218f8801ca2b106119_rw_1920.jpg?h=3e70946439d6e6326c1bd3efc5d20e51" alt="Nature" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
  </div>

  <div class="song-box">
    <img src="https://pro2-bar-s3-cdn-cf6.myportfolio.com/0d5a2028d7a7f8febf676a97648ea300/05851b218f8801ca2b106119_rw_1920.jpg?h=3e70946439d6e6326c1bd3efc5d20e51" alt="Nature" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
  </div>

  <div class="song-box">
    <img src="https://pro2-bar-s3-cdn-cf6.myportfolio.com/0d5a2028d7a7f8febf676a97648ea300/05851b218f8801ca2b106119_rw_1920.jpg?h=3e70946439d6e6326c1bd3efc5d20e51" alt="Nature" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
  </div>

  <div class="song-box">
    <img src="https://pro2-bar-s3-cdn-cf6.myportfolio.com/0d5a2028d7a7f8febf676a97648ea300/05851b218f8801ca2b106119_rw_1920.jpg?h=3e70946439d6e6326c1bd3efc5d20e51" alt="Nature" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
  </div>

  <div class="song-box">
    <img src="https://pro2-bar-s3-cdn-cf6.myportfolio.com/0d5a2028d7a7f8febf676a97648ea300/05851b218f8801ca2b106119_rw_1920.jpg?h=3e70946439d6e6326c1bd3efc5d20e51" alt="Nature" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
  </div>

  <div class="song-box">
    <img src="https://pro2-bar-s3-cdn-cf6.myportfolio.com/0d5a2028d7a7f8febf676a97648ea300/05851b218f8801ca2b106119_rw_1920.jpg?h=3e70946439d6e6326c1bd3efc5d20e51" alt="Nature" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
  </div>

  <div class="song-box">
    <img src="https://pro2-bar-s3-cdn-cf6.myportfolio.com/0d5a2028d7a7f8febf676a97648ea300/05851b218f8801ca2b106119_rw_1920.jpg?h=3e70946439d6e6326c1bd3efc5d20e51" alt="Nature" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
  </div>

  <div class="song-box">
    <img src="https://pro2-bar-s3-cdn-cf6.myportfolio.com/0d5a2028d7a7f8febf676a97648ea300/05851b218f8801ca2b106119_rw_1920.jpg?h=3e70946439d6e6326c1bd3efc5d20e51" alt="Nature" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
  </div>

</div>



<div class="black-bar">

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the result by just wrapping the `flex-container` and `black-bar` with a wrapper/container to stack them vertically (using flex) and dynamically calculate the remaining height for `flex-container` using css `calc()`.

Link to the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Baliga/7s8k910f/20/

Comment: @MarkDenom can you please specify what exactly is the current issue. is it the scrollbar?

Answer (score 0):

Because the black bar has a position of `fixed`. Remove it and its default position of `static` will put it back into the normal flow of the layout.

```css
.flex-container {
  max-width: 1700px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.black-bar {
  background-color: #242424;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  //position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="song-box">
    <img src="https://pro2-bar-s3-cdn-cf6.myportfolio.com/0d5a2028d7a7f8febf676a97648ea300/05851b218f8801ca2b106119_rw_1920.jpg?h=3e70946439d6e6326c1bd3efc5d20e51" alt="Nature" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
  </div>

  <div class="song-box">
    <img src="https://pro2-bar-s3-cdn-cf6.myportfolio.com/0d5a2028d7a7f8febf676a97648ea300/05851b218f8801ca2b106119_rw_1920.jpg?h=3e70946439d6e6326c1bd3efc5d20e51" alt="Nature" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
  </div>

  <div class="song-box">
    <img src="https://pro2-bar-s3-cdn-cf6.myportfolio.com/0d5a2028d7a7f8febf676a97648ea300/05851b218f8801ca2b106119_rw_1920.jpg?h=3e70946439d6e6326c1bd3efc5d20e51" alt="Nature" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
  </div>

  <div class="song-box">
    <img src="https://pro2-bar-s3-cdn-cf6.myportfolio.com/0d5a2028d7a7f8febf676a97648ea300/05851b218f8801ca2b106119_rw_1920.jpg?h=3e70946439d6e6326c1bd3efc5d20e51" alt="Nature" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
  </div>

  <div class="song-box">
    <img src="https://pro2-bar-s3-cdn-cf6.myportfolio.com/0d5a2028d7a7f8febf676a97648ea300/05851b218f8801ca2b106119_rw_1920.jpg?h=3e70946439d6e6326c1bd3efc5d20e51" alt="Nature" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
  </div>

  <div class="song-box">
    <img src="https://pro2-bar-s3-cdn-cf6.myportfolio.com/0d5a2028d7a7f8febf676a97648ea300/05851b218f8801ca2b106119_rw_1920.jpg?h=3e70946439d6e6326c1bd3efc5d20e51" alt="Nature" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
  </div>

  <div class="song-box">
    <img src="https://pro2-bar-s3-cdn-cf6.myportfolio.com/0d5a2028d7a7f8febf676a97648ea300/05851b218f8801ca2b106119_rw_1920.jpg?h=3e70946439d6e6326c1bd3efc5d20e51" alt="Nature" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
  </div>

  <div class="song-box">
    <img src="https://pro2-bar-s3-cdn-cf6.myportfolio.com/0d5a2028d7a7f8febf676a97648ea300/05851b218f8801ca2b106119_rw_1920.jpg?h=3e70946439d6e6326c1bd3efc5d20e51" alt="Nature" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
  </div>

  <div class="song-box">
    <img src="https://pro2-bar-s3-cdn-cf6.myportfolio.com/0d5a2028d7a7f8febf676a97648ea300/05851b218f8801ca2b106119_rw_1920.jpg?h=3e70946439d6e6326c1bd3efc5d20e51" alt="Nature" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
  </div>

  <div class="song-box">
    <img src="https://pro2-bar-s3-cdn-cf6.myportfolio.com/0d5a2028d7a7f8febf676a97648ea300/05851b218f8801ca2b106119_rw_1920.jpg?h=3e70946439d6e6326c1bd3efc5d20e51" alt="Nature" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
  </div>

  <div class="song-box">
    <img src="https://pro2-bar-s3-cdn-cf6.myportfolio.com/0d5a2028d7a7f8febf676a97648ea300/05851b218f8801ca2b106119_rw_1920.jpg?h=3e70946439d6e6326c1bd3efc5d20e51" alt="Nature" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
  </div>

  <div class="song-box">
    <img src="https://pro2-bar-s3-cdn-cf6.myportfolio.com/0d5a2028d7a7f8febf676a97648ea300/05851b218f8801ca2b106119_rw_1920.jpg?h=3e70946439d6e6326c1bd3efc5d20e51" alt="Nature" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
  </div>

  <div class="song-box">
    <img src="https://pro2-bar-s3-cdn-cf6.myportfolio.com/0d5a2028d7a7f8febf676a97648ea300/05851b218f8801ca2b106119_rw_1920.jpg?h=3e70946439d6e6326c1bd3efc5d20e51" alt="Nature" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
  </div>

  <div class="song-box">
    <img src="https://pro2-bar-s3-cdn-cf6.myportfolio.com/0d5a2028d7a7f8febf676a97648ea300/05851b218f8801ca2b106119_rw_1920.jpg?h=3e70946439d6e6326c1bd3efc5d20e51" alt="Nature" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
  </div>

  <div class="song-box">
    <img src="https://pro2-bar-s3-cdn-cf6.myportfolio.com/0d5a2028d7a7f8febf676a97648ea300/05851b218f8801ca2b106119_rw_1920.jpg?h=3e70946439d6e6326c1bd3efc5d20e51" alt="Nature" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
  </div>

</div>



<div class="black-bar">

</div>
```

Comment: I see what you mean but at this point it will be stuck to the bottom, I want it to be at the bottom of the browser and follow along when scrolling, I might have to make the flexbox container scrollable, instead of the entire page

Comment: @MarkDenom Give the flexbox container a margin-bottom so it doesn't fall behing the bar.